# how to measure current generated by wind turbine

Tags: current, current-measurement

I was wondering how to measure the current generated by a wind turbine?

I tried connecting the voltmeter to the metal connectors of the motor (the 2 metal parts that stick out the motor) and set my voltmeter to amperage, but it showed 0A when the motor was turning. So I attached a resistor as a load and then tried measuring the amperage, but I still got 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to measure current of anything else?

Comment: Did you measure the voltage? how are you turning it? what kind of resistor. Please be specific.

Comment: What wind generator are you using with your turbine? A DC generator can be measured one way, but an AC gen. would need a diff. measurement.

Comment: I used a 3.9k Ω resistor and it is a 9-18V DC motor. I measured voltage and it was 1V. However, I measured voltage without any load.

Comment: It could be the same because there's a light internal load and 3.9k isn't enough of a diff. Or the speed is too low. Both the mechanical energy put into the motor (effectively the speed) and the load are going to affect the voltage / current. So if you're just spinning the blades for 2 cycles for only a second and you're not really loading it, you might not see much difference in output. You might need to actually get some wind moving it and use a load more like 100 R or even lower. I think you want to load it enough to the point where it actually slows down the blades slightly.

Comment: What is the "nameplate capacity" of your turbine/generator (rated output power)? If your 9-18VDC generator is rated for, say, 1KW, then it is rated for 55.6A current output @ 18V. This would be about a 1/3 (0.324 to be exact) Ohm load. Of 100W rating would be a 3.24ohm load. Either way, this means that you'll need a **FAR** lower impedance load than the 3.9K resistor you tried. -- Also, as @squarewav pointed out, you'll need a way of turning your turbine with up to rated force/speed for appropriate testing (a power drill maybe).

Answer (score 1):

If it's making 1V and you have a 3900Ω load, that's about 0.00025A.  Not really detectable with your average multimeter.  Also you need to put the multimeter in *series*.  Like this:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-measure-current-on-an-electronic-circuit.html

Answer (score -1):

Motor on wind turbine need some speed, low speed generator could not make any power, see tag on motor . DC motor permanent magnet could work in wide range speed. Let say you need  Load like bulbs or battery to check how much current its take. See tag on motor what it say.